# Problem joining 2 tables and aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got an issue joining 2 tables using the sum function. The aggregate returns the total sum for the whole period not dividing it based on the columns from the joined table. Any idea what to do to get revenue per day and retail? Thank you.
Syntax:

```
Select Date, Retailname, sum(Revenue) 
From table1 t1 
Join table2 t2 
On t1.primarykey = t2.primarykey 
Group by Date, Retailname
```

Result:

```
Date    Retailname    Revenue  
X          Name1.          224
X.         Name2.          224 
X.         Name3.          224 
X.         Name4.          224
```

........
Desires result:

```
Date    Retailname    Revenue  
X          Name1.          25 
X.         Name2.          75 
X.         Name3.          96 
X.         Name4.          28
```

........

I tried correlated subquery from select clause but it returns the same result.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data in table1 and table2

Answer (score 0):

For joining process your data will be duplicate, so for that you sum function calculated sum from duplicated records. You can firstly sum your table before joining, and after summing and grouping you can join second table, or vice versa.

Some examples:

```
select t1.* from (
    select id, sum(val) from table1
    group by id 
) t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

or

```
select t1.* from table2 t2
inner join 
(   select id, sum(val) from table1
    group by id 
) t1 on t1.id = t2.id
```

And for not viewing duplicate records you can use distinct.